# Is "X509v3 Key Usage: Certificate Sign" required for passing openssl verify?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509

Below are three self-signed certificates I've made and verified with `openssl verify`:

---

**Certificate #1:**

```
X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
    CA:FALSE
X509v3 Key Usage: 
    Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
```

This self-signed certificate is not a CA, it's missing the "Certificate Sign" value, and it fails verification:

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile ca_false_cert.crt ca_false_cert.crt 
error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate
error ca_false_cert.crt: verification failed
```

---

**Certificate #2:**

```
X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
    CA:FALSE
X509v3 Key Usage: 
    Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Certificate Sign
```

This self-signed certificate is not a CA, it includes the "Certificate Sign" value, and it passes verification:

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile ca_false_sign_cert.crt ca_false_sign_cert.crt
ca_false_sign_cert.crt: OK
```

---

**Certificate #3:**

```
X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
    CA:TRUE
X509v3 Key Usage: 
    Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
```

This self-signed certificate is a CA, it's missing the "Certificate Sign" value, and it fails verification:

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile ca_true_sign_cert.crt ca_true_sign_cert.crt
error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate
error ca_true_sign_cert.crt: verification failed
```

---

My two questions are:

1. Is `X509v3 Key Usage: Certificate Sign` necessary for a self-signed certificate (or for CA certificates in general)?
2. Are non-CA (i.e. without `X509v3 Basic Constraints: CA:TRUE`, or with `CA:FALSE`) self-signed certificates even valid? Or does `openssl verify` overlook this?

Comment: The problem here is that `openssl` is not the definitive test for certificate verification - it's merely a convenient and popular tool.  RFC 5280 doesn't say much about the processing of the trust-anchors (`-CAfile`), so implementations can and do vary while still being compliant.  Even if it some of these extensions seem to be irrelevant with `openssl verify` it doesn't mean the results will be the same if the relying party is Microsoft or Java for example.  To be safe, follow the RFC as much as you can.  Granted that's harder with self-signed certs as they're the trust-anchor and end-entity.

Comment: Certificate#1 and certificate#3 succeed for me too with OpenSSL 1.1.1. They fail with LibreSSL 2.9.0 though but succeed again with later versions of LibreSSL like 3.3.3

Comment: I looked into the RFC and I saw that "if the keyCertSign bit is asserted, then the cA bit in the basic constraints extension (Section 4.2.1.9) MUST also be asserted", so it seems that certificate #2 isn't valid, and OpenSSL gets it wrong.
@SteffenUllrich I also used OpenSSL 1.1.1 so I'm surprised #1 and #3 worked for you.

Comment: @GabeL: maybe there is something different with your certificates. Here are mine: [cert1](https://pastebin.com/Y3mV0f8V), [cert2](https://pastebin.com/NZPqwMWT), [cert3](https://pastebin.com/wvFyMHZA)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I tried `openssl verify -CAfile cert1.crt cert1.crt` and I got the same "unable to get local issuer certificate" error as I got for my first certificate. Did you provide some other argument?

Comment: @GabeL: no, I did it exactly like you did. Checked with OpenSSL 1.1.1h but also OpenSSL 3.0.1, LibreSSL 3.3.3. It fails with the same error message as you gave with LibreSSL 2.9.0 though.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I see, I used 1.1.1 (no h), not sure what's different between the two versions. But either way that supports garethTheRed's point that every implementation might have a different verification standard.